# Swift how to pass in an object type to a function and use it to create new object

Tags: swift, types

I have some code where I am trying to make a generic jsonDecode function to decode json into codable objects. The issue is I do not know how to write it so that I can call the function and pass in the type of codable object that I want to decode to.

Here is what I currently have but it obviously does not work:

```
static func decodeJSON(_ filename: String, as objectType: Any) {
        // Earlier part of function gets jsonData variable
        do {
            return try JSONDecoder().decode(objectType.self, from: jsonData)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

What do I need to set the `objectType` parameter's type to? and then how would I go about calling that where I have `objectType.self`? Do I need to use generics?

Comment: "Do I need to use generics?" Yes.

Comment: Model your `decodeJSON` method on the `decode` method of `TopLevelDecoder` (which `JSONDecoder` conforms to).

Comment: Im assuming I would have to use a generic which conforms to a specific protocol that all "type types" conform to no?

Comment: @HangarRash, I looked at it and rewrote the function declaration to `func decodeJSON<T>(_ filename: String, as objectType: T.Type )`. Pretty sure it will work since I don't see any errors, will update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @HangarRash replied, modeling the function on `TopLevelDecoder`'s `decode` method fixed the issue. I changed the function declaration line to
`func decodeJSON<T: Codable>(_ filename: String, as objectType: T.Type )` which does work to decode into any object type. Say you want to decode to a class named `RandomClass` you would do `decodeJSON("filename", as: RandomClass.self)`

Comment: Minor nit pick but you should change the `<T: Codable>` part to `<T: Decodable>` since you only need a class that can be decoded, not necessarily encoded.